# Same queries giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can someone please explain why the first query gives error and second query doesn't?

```
select * from employee  Where empDate < '20.06.2013 09:11:00 ' 

select * from employee  Where empDate < '11.04.2013 14:40:00 '
```

The first query causes an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Really hard to understand when I am passing same date format to both queries. The column data type for `empDate` is `Datetime`. What is wrong here?

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: As you seem to be using a custom date format (`20.06.2013`), could it be that the format is `MM.DD.YYYY` and not `DD.MM.YYYY` as you seem to assume?

Comment: Can someone tell why this question is downvoted? Dont use your power because you have

Comment: See https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries.  The first date could easily be the 6th day of the 20th month, which is just wrong.

Comment: ARe you sure the datetime format is DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: @Elias i am getting above value from GUI. The column format is datetime and that is 100% true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it looks like you can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'20.06.2013 09:11:00',103)
```

To convert your date format to a proper DATETIME for comparison:

```
select * 
from employee  
Where empDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,'20.06.2013 09:11:00',103)
```

The third parameter of the `CONVERT()` function is for defining the 'style', you can see a list of formats here:  [CAST and CONVERT - Date and Time Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Working perfectly. Smooth as butter :) Thannks

Answer (score 4):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server for dates - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

In your concrete case - if your `Language` setting of SQL Server is set to `German`, it works:

```
SET LANGUAGE german

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '20.06.2013 09:11:00')
```

and the date is interpreted as 20th June 2013.

However, if your SQL Server setting is set to `English` (very often the default!), then it won't work:

```
SET LANGUAGE English

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '20.06.2013 09:11:00')

Changed language setting to us_english.  
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3  
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

since in this case, it's interpreted as the 6th day of the 20th month of 2013 ...

So you need to rewrite your query to be:

```
select * from employee where empDate < '2013-06-20T09:11:00' 
select * from employee where empDate < '2013-04-11T14:40:00'
```

then these queries work - regardless of what your `Language` setting in SQL Server is set to.

Comment: can you tell how can i rewrite this query? I also tried using Convert(varchar(20),'20.06.2013 09:11:22' but doesnt work

Comment: When can't you rely on YYYY-MM-DD as being equivalent to YYYYMMDD?

Comment: But i am getting values of date from GUI. How can i convert this in sql?

Comment: @GoatCO: because that **won't work** - just try it! `SET LANGUAGE german; select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-20')` (or `French`) will ***FAIL***

Comment: @Happy: well, in that case, you should be using ***parameters*** in your query anyway, which would save you from all this grief!

Comment: @marc_s how to use this parameters? Also then is it not possible to convert this date in the format you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @Marc_s You are wrong when you state: "YYYYMMDD for just dates (no time portion); note here: no dashes!, that's very important! YYYY-MM-DD is NOT independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will NOT work in all situations!"  That's not true, for `DATE` YYYY-MM-DD is equivalent to `YYYYMMDD`, always.  `DATETIME` is another story and will depend on language settings.  In the context of the question it's clear they need `DATETIME`, but the wording could be more clear as to not create confusion.

Comment: @GoatCO do you know how can i solve this? How can i convert this date to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @Happy sure thing, answer submitted.

Comment: @GoatCO: if you read my answer carefully, then I said: *If you use SQL Server 2008 and the `DATE` datatype..., then you can indeed also use the YYYY-MM-DD* - that's **exactly** what I was saying all along! The tricky beast is converting to `DATETIME` - another reason not to use that anymore

Comment: @marc_s ah, my whoops!

Answer (score 1):

My only explanation is that the database is set up to expect the month ahead of the day.

The second query can be interpreted as Nov-04, 2013 in this format, but the first query would have an error because there is no month number 20.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when date is not valid, what is happening here in your case data is getting passed as MM-DD-YYYY

So when you passed 20.06.2013

Month became 20 which is wrong.

Always try to give date in proper format you can rely on 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: @GoatCO: because that advice **won't work** - just try it! `SET LANGUAGE german; select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-20')` will ***FAIL*** - this is ***NOT*** good / safe advice!

Comment: I think that @Ashutosh is just pointing out that there are reliable formats available (YYYY-MM-DD), and that there is no 20th month in any given format. It's true that not all nations use the same format, which is a critical point. To be fair, Ashutosh hasn't said 'use CONVERT', just 'check your date format'.

Comment: @WilliamM-B - no, marc_s was pointing out that even the `YYYY-MM-DD` is *not* always reliable, and you *can't* rely on it.  `YYYYMMDD` format is reliable, however.  The answer is wrong.

Comment: In this case, OP needs `DATETIME` so this answer is problematic, but it's worth noting that when using a `DATE` and not `DATETIME` YYYY-MM-DD is always equivalent to YYYYMMDD.

`SET LANGUAGE german select CAST('2013-06-20' AS DATE)`
`SET LANGUAGE german select CAST('2013-06-20' AS DATETIME)`

Comment: @GoatCO: and converting to `DATETIME2` also works - it's just the conversion to `DATETIME` that behaves this oddly .... but when converting to `DATETIME`, `YYYY-MM-DD` just doesn't work reliably.